# PHP Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am having trouble instantiating (?) the PHPMailer class. I can only get it to work if I `require` Composer's `vendor/autoload.php` at the beginning of the page that handles the mailing function.

First, here's my directory structure:

```
root
 ├─ www
 │   ├─ includes
 │   │   ├─ headers.php
 │   │   └─ mail.php
 │   └─ index.php
 └─ vendor
     ├─ composer
     │   ├─ ...
     │   └─ ...
     ├─ phpmailer
     │   ├─ ...
     │   └─ ...
     └─ autoload.php
```

The file `index.php` begins with:

```
<?php
    require (__DIR__.'/includes/headers.php');
?>
```

The file `includes/headers.php` begins with:

```
<?php
    require (__DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php');
```

... and then goes on to set things like timezone and error reporting etc.

I have a contact form on `index.php` which submits POST data via ajax to `includes/mail.php`.

`mail.php` looks something like this:

```
<?php
    validate_post_data();

    function validate_post_data() {
        // Checks POST data is OK, then calls another 
        // function to send the mail using PHPMailer

        if ($valid) {
            send_mail ($name, $email, $message);
        } else {
            return "Error with POST data";
        }
    }

    function send_mail($name, $email, $message) {
        $mail = new \PHPMailer;

        ...

        $mail->send();
    }
?>
```

This produces the following error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /srv/www/example.com/www/includes/mail.php
```

I can *only* get the script to work if I put `require(__DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php')` at the beginning of the file `mail.php`.

Is there a <strike>better</strike> correct way of accomplishing this?

Thank you.

Comment: If you can get the script by including the file probably the class PHPMailer is there? uhm?

Comment: I guess so, yes. I just thought: could the reason for the class not being found be because `mail.php` is called via ajax, and therefore `mail.php` effectively has no knowledge of what files were included on `index.php`? (I have no idea what terminology to use.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can require headers.php in your mail.php script. I think when your post request arrives at the script mail.php, it has no idea that autoloading has been done in the index.php.